# Render a Bezier curve in the game engine

Tags: game-engine, bezier-curves

I would like to visualize a curve when the blender game engine is running. In the editor the curve is clearly visible:

[image]

But when I run the game engine it is not

[image]

What can I do to visualize the curve when running the game engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curves are a unique object type, they won't render without depth in the default renderer and even with depth, they won't render in the BGE as these and paths aren't supported.

To render these, you have to convert to a mesh, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Mesh from Curve/Meta/...*. You can always duplicate and move the original to another layer before converting so you have a backup and in most cases, if the converted mesh is simple enough, you can convert it back to a curve via the same menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to loose that ability to edit the curve you could also add a cylinder with an *Array* and a *Curve Modifier*, this would render in the BGE.

[image]

Comment: Won't quite get that smooth look but a good alternative.