# BGE: trying to connect many nodes with lines, but would prefer bezier splines instead of straight lines

Tags: game-engine

This was touched on here:

[Render a Bezier curve in the game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/render-a-bezier-curve-in-the-game-engine)

I am trying to make what amounts to a 3d mind mappijg program, but in reality is a multi-data type conceptual mapping took bringing together authors, citations, keywords, Geographic location (as well as time) etc. The idea is a big project, but it would be skimmed way way way down for a proof of concept.

Question: There are times where i would like to use render.drawline, and other times I would like that line to be a bezier curve. Is there anyway to do this without the curve being a mesh object (imagine having a thousand?) Should the same be done with straight lines?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `bgl` module to draw the curves from a Python script. You can use [mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier()](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/mathutils.geometry.html#mathutils.geometry.interpolate_bezier) to compute intermediate points (depending on scale etc.). Not too sure about the performance, though.